# How to sort data by column of a table created in Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

If we create a table in Spree, is there any predefined method to sort its content?

I had found `sort_link  @search`, does anyone know how to use that?

Also if no predefined methods are available for sorting, what are the other best possible ways to accomplish the task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution is 'ransack gem', it provides the wonderful way to get the search and sort the results.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the `order` method from ActiveRecord:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering